# How to append Complex Data Type to View Model before submit of form post method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am using Form Post method to submit data to controller in my MVC application.
My MVC Application controller method accepting ViewModel.
I have added new list of other viewModel and I want to pass the data to that newly added viewmodel.

Sample Code ( not fully executed )

Controller Existing Code

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(ProductViewModel productViewModel)
{
    //some operation
} 

public class ProductViewModel
{
    Branch_Product_Taxes = new List<Branch_Product_TaxesViewModel>();
} 

 //viewmodel
```

`$('#ProductForm').submit(); //javascript form submit method`

`var ObjectList = new Array()`

Now I have added List of Objects in Object List
I want to pass this list controller

Comment: Please fix your code markup - right now it's unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create hidden elements as per your complex data type
Consider following issue
If you need to post employee list with attribute like name etc then go through following code.

Your view Model something like

```
 public class ProductViewModel
{
     public IList<Employees> = new List<Employees>();
}
```

Javascript Code

```
    var  html = '<input type="hidden" name="Employees[0].Name" value="Employee1"/>';
    html+='<input type="hidden" name="Employees[0].Designation" value="Des1"/>';
    html+='<input type="hidden" name="Employees[1].Name" value="Employee2"/>';
    html+='<input type="hidden" name="Employees[1].Designation" value="Des2"/>';
    $('#ProductForm').append(html);
    $('#ProductForm').submit();
```

You will get list of two records as (0 and 1 ) index.

You can use for loop and generate hidden html dynamically and append it before Form submit.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the list as property inside the ViewModel you are passing, by default modelbinder does not consider the fields like

```
Branch_Product_Taxes = new List<Branch_Product_TaxesViewModel>();
```

you need to define the property Like

```
 public IList<Branch_Product_TaxesViewModel> Branch_Product_Taxes  { get; set; }
```

Comment: Okay I will do it. but how can I post my List to Form before submit()